# E/[Error]: sh: /data/data/: Permission denied

Tags: android, shell, root

I am getting this error why I try to go to /data/data/

```
E/[Error]: sh: /data/data/: Permission denied
```

But I do not understand why. When I press the button, superuser asks for root permissions correctly, but it still tells me permission denied in the log... that shouldn't be happening if I give root permissions, right?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnCon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnCon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RunWithRoot("su shell /data/data/");
        }
    });
}

private void RunWithRoot(String textView) {
    try {
        String line;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(textView);
        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
        InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

        stdin.write(("ls\n").getBytes());
        stdin.write("exit\n".getBytes());
        stdin.flush();

        stdin.close();
        BufferedReader br =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("[Output]", line);
        }
        br.close();
        br =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("[Error]", line);
        }
        br.close();

        process.waitFor();
        process.destroy();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me understand this better, because to my understanding; root is the top most permission.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `su shell /data/data` you run as shell user which has no access there. Try using something like `su -c "sh&&cd /data/data"`